# How to close the MauiCommunityToolkit Popup from Viewmodel

Tags: popup, maui, windows-community-toolkit, maui-community-toolkit

I want close a CommunityToolkit Popup in my Viewmodel.
I tried using a `WeakReferenceMessenger` to receive a message like this:

```
        public mypopup()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<string, string>(this, "popup", (r, d) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(message: "received message");
            if (d == "close")
            {
                WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Unregister<string>(this);
                MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { this.Close(); });
            }
        });
    }
```

And somewhere else I use this to send a message

```
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send<string, string>("close", "popup");
```

The 1st call works. And the SECOND time it will raise a `System.NullReferenceException` in *MauiPopup.windows.cs* Function `void CleanUp()  Target.ContextFlyout = null;`

I also tried like this in message receive:

```
MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { this.Close(); });
```

the same happens.
I wonder if there is a solution or a better way to close popup from somewhere else without transferring the handle of popup.

Comment: ou of curiosity why don't you close it from the code behind of the contentpage that opened it in the first place ?

Comment: @ss1969 you expect to close the popup from the popup viewmodel? if this is not the case, why you want to close a popup from another viewmodel? if you Expect some result to close, first you should get that result and then you open or not the popup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did this in my code

```
        PopupPage p = new PopupPage();
        Application.Current.MainPage.ShowPopup(p);
        await new TaskFactory().StartNew(() => { Thread.Sleep(5000); });
        p.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<Button
     Command="{Binding CloseClickCommand}"
     CommandParameter="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type mct:Popup}}}"
     Text="Close" />
```

...

```
public async Task CloseClickCommand(object obj)
{
    if (obj is Popup popup) 
    {
       popup.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this
in xamal

```
<toolkit:Popup
    x:Class="VSTORE.Views.Popups.UserAdresPopupView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:VSTORE.ViewModels.PopupsViewModel"
    x:Name="MYPOPUP"

  <Button
      Command="{Binding CloseCommand}"
      CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference MYPOPUP}}"
      Style="{StaticResource ConfirmButton}"
      Text="CLOSE" />
```

in viewmodel

```
 [RelayCommand]
 public async Task Close(Popup popup)
 {
     popup.Close();
    await DisplayToast("Closed using button");
 }
```

Comment: This feels like it breaks the convention of the ViewModel having no knowledge of the View

Comment: @DavidPilkington sir I did not get you, Giving the reference to the view by name in command parameter is really breaking the viewmodel and view convention

Answer (score 0):

In MVVM, the View would subscribe to the events of the ViewModel
The viewModel would look like the following:

```
public delegate Task CloseHandler<T> (T result);

public class TheViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public event CloseHandler<bool> OnClose;
    public TheViewModel()
    {
        CloseCommand = new RelayCommand<bool>(async result => await OnClose?.Invoke(result));
    }

    public ICommand CloseCommand { get; set; }        
}
```

And the codebehind of the view would look like this:

```
public partial class ThePopup : Popup
{
    public ThePopup(TheViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = vm;
        vm.OnClose += async result => await CloseAsync(result, CancellationToken.None);
    }
}
```

You can find a simple example [here](https://github.com/adpartage/maui-showcases)

[image]